# Directly using the constructor of class in other class constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

I have this:

```
class point{
public:
    point()=default;
    point(int x,int y):x(x),y(y){}
    int x,y;
}
```

and this:

```
class quad{
public:   
    quad()=default;
    quad(point a,point b,point c, point c):a(a),b(b),c(c),d(d){};

    point a,b,c,d;
}
```

In the main, I can do this:

```
point a(0,0),b(1,1),c(2,2),d(3,3);
quad q(a,b,c,d);
```

Or directly this:

```
quad q(point(0,0),point(1,1),point(2,2),point(3,3));
```

but of course NOT this:

```
quad q(0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3); // I know it's wrong
```

**The question:**

Is it possible without declaring a new constructor that take 8 integers in `quad` to use the last code? the motivation of this question is the way that `emplace_back` works. To be more clear:

```
std::vector<point> points;
points.push_back(point(0,0)); // you have to pass object
points.emplace_back(0,0);  // you have just to send the arguments of the constructor
```

Comment: "_without declaring a new constructor_" - why would that be a problem? And would `quad q({0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3})` be acceptable?

Comment: `std::vector<T>::emplace_back` works by perfect-forwarding the arguments to the constructor of `T`. Don't think that's particularly applicable here.

Comment: "that's particularly applicable here" you mean not possible or it is not a best practise ?

Comment: I mean it's not very useful and a bit of a different concept. Perfect-forwarding integers is unnecessary, and you'd be dealing with constructing multiple objects. This is more similar to `std::piecewise_construct` constructors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible without declaring a new constructor.

One option is to just pass in brace initializers for each of the points:

```
quad q({0,0},{1,1},{2,2},{3,3});
```